# Error when trying to change file name to date created?

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm using PowerShell to change a bunch of video file names from "IMG-3523" etc to their respective dates and hour/minute/second created.

However, for some reason, it's giving me an error saying something along the lines of "that file name already exists, cannot create duplicate". However this seems impossible, as I couldn't have taken 2 videos at the exact same start time (hh:mm:ss).

**Here's the code I used** (from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v82gkPYZa7Y) tutorial):

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss ddd") + ($_.Extension)}
```

**Here's the error I get:**

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

At line:1 char:17

- ... ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM- ...
- 
- CategoryInfo : WriteError: (C:\Users\IMG_5956.MOV:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: You could try adding microseconds to the format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss.fff ddd"`. Also, if you don't want to also process Directories, only files, then always append `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. Perhaps that is why your code fails. And, if all the files are of type `*.mov`, then append `-Filter '*.mov'` as well.

Comment: Run this code to find out which files are generating duplicate names: `gci -af | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $_.Name ; NewName = $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss ddd") + ($_.Extension) }} | Group NewName | ? Count -gt 1 | select -expand group`